# ansible - how do I find the roles of a given node?

Tags: ansible

It seems like a simple thing to ask.

I have a system with many ansible roles at play. I have a login node, I want to find out what ansible roles it satisfies so that I can provision more like it. Is there a file somewhere that contains this information? A command? A playbook I can write?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need but you can try this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inv_file --limit=your_login_node --list-tasks
```